# Find This Weeks Monday

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

How do I get the date of this current week's Monday. Where Monday is the first day of the week.  So if I was to look up this weeks it would return the date 1/16/2012

I am using VBScript and ASP

Many thanks in advance..

Paul

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Effectively, the Weekday function returns Sunday=1, Monday=2, etc.  To get the Monday of the same week, you want to subtract:

```
Sunday (1): 6 days
Monday (2): 0 days
Tuesday(3): 1 day
...
Saturday(7): 5 days.
```

Or
     Days to subtract = (Weekday - 2 + 7) Mod 7

So if `d` is a date, the Monday of the same week can be written as:

```
mondayofsameweek = DateAdd("d", -((Weekday(d) + 7 - 2) Mod 7), d)
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript has a function called WeekDay, it return 1 - 7, not sure whether 1 is Monday though, usually you can twiddle with that.

Either way get the weekday Thursday = 4? , so then you just need to take three days off your date with thae DateAdd function

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript WeekDay returns the day of the week, starting with Sunday=1 (VBScript can be quirky like that).  So just subtract two (Monday=2) from that value and call DateAdd.

```
monday = DateAdd("d",(WeekDay(Date())-2),Date())
```

Comment: You forgot to multiply to -1 so the days are substracted `monday = DateAdd("d",(WeekDay(Date())-2)*-1,Date())`

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is a bit old, but I figured I'd share my working solution that I think is a bit more concise. 
Where `dDate` is your current date:

```
dDate = DateAdd("d", -(WeekDay(dDate, vbMonday) - 1), dDate)
```

The second parameters of `WeekDay` is the day you want the week to 'start'. For me, in the US, `WeekDay` corresponds the default second parameter to `vbSunday`. Specifying `vbMonday`, we just get the difference (base 1) between our current weekday and Monday. 
Subtract 1 and add the inverse to your current date should obtain your result.

Example:

```
WeekDay(2018-03-20, vbMonday) = -((2) - 1) = DateAdd("d", -1, 2018-03-20)
```